# Ionic controller issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic to develop a hybrid app, but I found an issue. When I view a page with list, I click one list-item to go to another page, and use history to go back, I found that the list-page's controller is called again, but if I repeat the process, the controller will not be called again.

Comment: Add some code here

Comment: solved already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'abstract':true,
```

add this code in route.